# Check if something is an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Currently I have the following issue. I need to figure out how I can check if something is an array.

```
if(isset($_GET['koophuur']) && $_GET['koophuur'] == 'koop'){
        $this->objects->search->koop          = true;
        $this->objects->search->min_koopprijs = (isset($_GET['min_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['min_prijs'])?$_GET['min_prijs']:null);
        $this->objects->search->max_koopprijs = (isset($_GET['max_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['max_prijs'])?$_GET['max_prijs']:null);
    }elseif(isset($_GET['koophuur']) && $_GET['koophuur'] == 'huur'){
        $this->objects->search->huur          = true;
        $this->objects->search->min_huurprijs = (isset($_GET['min_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['min_prijs'])?$_GET['min_prijs']:null);
        $this->objects->search->max_huurprijs = (isset($_GET['max_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['max_prijs'])?$_GET['max_prijs']:null);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['koophuurgarage']) && $_GET['koophuurgarage'] == 'koopgarage'){
        $this->objects->search->koop          = true;
        $this->objects->search->min_koopprijs = (isset($_GET['min_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['min_prijs'])?$_GET['min_prijs']:null);
        $this->objects->search->max_koopprijs = (isset($_GET['max_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['max_prijs'])?$_GET['max_prijs']:null);
    }elseif(isset($_GET['koophuurgarage']) && $_GET['koophuurgarage'] == 'huurgarage'){
        $this->objects->search->huur          = true;
        $this->objects->search->min_huurprijs = (isset($_GET['min_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['min_prijs'])?$_GET['min_prijs']:null);
        $this->objects->search->max_huurprijs = (isset($_GET['max_prijs']) && !empty($_GET['max_prijs'])?$_GET['max_prijs']:null);
    }
```

I am not getting these results in my search query right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `is_array` function. it return `true` if array else `false`.

```
is_array($variable);
```

Also if you need to check if the array is empty or not then

`empty($array)` : returns `true` if empty.

If need to check if any key is set or not then you can use

`isset($array['key'])` or `array_key_exists('key', $array)`

[is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) , [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: A blank array is also an array though